# How to add razor drop down dynamically in data table by clicking button?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am having datatable with 4 columns. I am having dropdown in my second column. I need to draw remaining column,with respect to selected dropdown value.

As values stored in dictionary I use JSON call to get values from controller. I even got the value. I need to load those with by selecting drop down option.. I individually added those drop down to my 1st row's 2nd cell, and finally able to load respected values. Now I am trying to add  that drop down dynamically to each row, by clicking add button. It some how ,shows `invalid token` or `unexpected token` error.. how to fix dis?

Codes for individual row:

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%;" id="tblAdd" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-hd">
     <thead>
         <tr class="gridheader">
             <td style="width: 10%;">S.No</td>
             <td style="width: 30%;">Id</td>
             <td style="width: 30%;">Type</td>
             <td style="width: 30%;">N O D</td>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td>
                 @{
                     List<string> LE = new List<string>();
                     Dictionary<string, string> test2 = DictionaryUtil.GetLEDictionary();
                     if (test2 != null && test2.Count() > 0)
                     {
                         foreach (var item in test2)
                         {
                             if (item.Key != string.Empty) { LE.Add(item.Key); }
                         }
                     }
                 }
                @Html.DropDownList("LE", new SelectList(@LE), "--Select Type--", new { @class = "form-control" })
             </td>
             <td> </td>
             <td></td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Controller get function:

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetLEDetails(string Type)
        {
            LE _LE = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Type))
            {
                _LE = GroupManager.GetLEWithType(Type);
                if (_LE != null)
                {
                    ViewBag._LT = _LE.Type1 != null ? _LE.Type1.Description : string.Empty;
                    ViewBag._NOD = _LE._NOD.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag._LT = string.Empty;
                    ViewBag._NOD = "0.0";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag._LT = string.Empty;
                ViewBag._NOD = "0.0";
            }
            //var data = ViewBag;
            //return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return Json(new { _LT = ViewBag._LT , _NOD = ViewBag._NOD }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Javascript to draw cells in table:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('change', $("LE"), function (el) {
          var LE = $("#LE").val();
          var LEUrl = '@Url.Action("GetLEDetails")';

         var t = $('#tblAdd').DataTable();

            $.getJSON(LEUrl, { Type: LE }, function (returnedJson) {
           var row = t.row(this);   
              var LT = returnedJson._LT;
            var NOD = returnedJson._NOD;
             t.cell(row, 2).data(LT).draw();
                t.cell(row, 3).data(NOD).draw();
                });
                });
  </script>
```

This creates dropdown in first row, while loading page and load data when change drop down, now I m trying to load my expected result.

For this my table be like

```
`

<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%;" id="tblAdd" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-hd">
         <thead>
             <tr class="gridheader">
                 <td style="width: 10%;">S.No</td>
                 <td style="width: 30%;">Id</td>
                 <td style="width: 30%;">Type</td>
                 <td style="width: 30%;">N O D</td>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             <tr>
                 <td></td>
                 <td>  </td>
                 <td> </td>
                 <td></td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
     </table>
```

and script be like

```
 <script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).on('click', $("btnAdd"), function () {
       var t = $('#tblAdd').DataTable();
        var row = t.row(this);
         @{
                List<string> LE = new List<string>();
                Dictionary<string, string> test2 = DictionaryUtil.GetLEDictionary();
                if (test2 != null && test2.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in test2)
                    {
                        if (item.Key != string.Empty) { LE.Add(item.Key); }
                    }
                }
            }
        t.cell(row, 1).data(@Html.DropDownList("LE", new SelectList(@LE), "--Select Type--", new { @class = "form-control" })).draw();   
    }
    </script>
```

How to do this? where did I did mistake? Likewise, can we able to delete those selected rows by clicking remove button?

Comment: Unclear to me...! Do u want to add values to dropdownlist?

Comment: I can add values and all .. I want to add my razor dropdown to my datatable under the column Id. When, I tried adding individually/directly under <td>, it works fine, but for the next row not created along with this drop down.. So clearly, what I need is, I need to add  my razor drop down in 2nd column,dynamically after clicking btnAdd.. Actual Op is, once I chose dropdown values, remaining cell in that row's filled with respect to dd value. Once one row is created,If I click btnAdd, I need the second row Id column must show the dropdown. Sir,May b my English is not so good,kindly adjust it.

Comment: First try to append string values like "Test" on add button click and then move forward step by step

Comment: @PrashantPimpale append() is not working, error shows undefined. but `t.cell(row, 2).data(LT).draw();` this line to draw cell values with respect to dd values, works fine. Using this same method, I tried to add dropdown, in my 2nd cell `t.cell(row, 1).data(@Html.DropDownList("LE", new SelectList(@LE), "--Select Type--", new { @class = "form-control" })).draw();`, this one only not working for me.. Error Shown is: "Unexpected token <" on this  dropdown adding line

Comment: how the data looks of `LT` variable

Comment: LT variable is get from controller JSON return from this `_LT = ViewBag._LT`. Its a string like Example: `LT = "Sample Data 3"`

Comment: So you need to construct a proper string of that dropdown markup

Comment: how to do that? I am new to this MVC,JSON things..

Comment: check this:https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/47681/how-to-add-html-element-for-row

Comment: sir, I have already gone through those sites, tried various methods too..still couldnt fine exact answer or method to fix...

Comment: I just checked, you can try on this demo:http://live.datatables.net/pehiwofe/28/

Comment: sir, as I follow your reference I tried to change my dropdown from razor to html type..`t.cell(row, 1).data('<select id="LE" class="form-control"><option> @LE</option></select>').draw();` This works for me to show drop down on column 2, but data's are not loaded, my selected data's are in `@LE` ..In my qstn, loading data's in @LE method is described..

Comment: How to add `@LE` loaded values into drop down using normal html dropdown values...

Comment: almost everything loaded while debug only it shows unexpected token error how to fix it? `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` while using this line  `t.cell(row, 1).data(@Html.DropDownList("leaveEntitlementDic", new SelectList(@leaveEntitlementDic), "--Select Type--", new { @class = "form-control" })).draw();`

Comment: Try putting ' single quotes at the start and end

Comment: tried already.. still showing same unexpected token < error